# IFrame .appendto does not work with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

A web page has a submit event, using jquery to record page form data on the web server as a third party.  The code works by appending an IFrame to the body of the html page,  passing data through the IFrame 'src' attribute to the web server using the query string.  The code works ok with browsers like IE, FF, and Chrome, but does not work with Safari.

Does anybody have an idea of how to get this working with Safari?

Code:
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('form').submit(function () {

```
        var url = "http://sitewritedata.aspx?accountID=123";
            jQuery('<iframe />', {
                id: 'iframe' + new Date().getTime(),
                name: 'iframe' + new Date().getTime(),
                width: '0',
                height: '0',
                frameborder: '0',
                src: url
            })
            .appendTo('body');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domain/port/protocal are the same, have you tried using `contents()`

```
jQuery('<iframe />', {
   id: 'iframe' + new Date().getTime(),
   name: 'iframe' + new Date().getTime(),
   width: '0',
   height: '0',
   frameborder: '0',
   src: url
})
.contents().appendTo('body');
```

Comment: domain/port/protocol are the same.  Tried using .contents(), but it did not work.